# Ошибка в выводе при присваивании

Tags: c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x;
    float z;
    scanf("%f", &x);
    if ((x < 3) && (x > 2))
    {
        x = z;
        printf("%f", z);
    }else
    {
        printf("bye\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В 10ой строке должно быть `z = x;`
Итоговый код:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float x;
    float z;
    scanf("%f", &x);
    if ((x < 3) && (x > 2))
    {
        z = x;
        printf("%f", z);
    }else
    {
        printf("bye\n");
    }
}
```